# How to display sum of values in local-storage with same username only?

Tags: angularjs, jsp, angular-local-storage

I have local-storage values in below :

```
[ {"id":1, "amount":24000000, "users":{"username":"user1"}}, {"id":2, "amount":10000000, "users":{"username":"user1"}}, {"id":3, "amount":20000000, "users":{"username":"user2"}} ]
```

**I display my local-storage in `JSP` using `AngularJS`.**

How to sum amount values in local-storage with same username only?.

**My controller :**

```
$scope.listOfCart = CartService.getAllCarts()||[];
$scope.items = $scope.listOfCart
```

**My JSP:**

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="cart in items">
    <td>{{cart.users.username}}</td>
    <td>{{cart.amount}}</td>
</tr>
```

Then how to display sum values amount with same username only? I try with forEach but display all amount username. I want to the displayed sum of amount only same username.

Comment: JSon format is not valid

Comment: Valid JSON - [
    {"id":1, "amount":24000000, "users":{"username":"user1"}},
    {"id":2, "amount":10000000, "users":{"username":"user1"}},
    {"id":3, "amount":20000000, "users":{"username":"user2"}}
]

Comment: yes sir thankyou, i will edit my JSON.

Comment: *display sum values amount with same username only*: I have no idea of what that means. You need to be much clearer. Note: JSP is completely irrelevant.

Comment: My intention is to display the sum of amount with the same username. Example i have username: user1. user1 have amount 100 and 50. user2 have amount 200. How to calculate sum of amount in user1? i try but still calculate sum of amount user1 and user2

Comment: What have you tried? Show your code.

Comment: I try with this code : 
`$scope.totalAmount = 0; $scope.items.forEach(function(item){ if (item){ item.total = item.quantity * item.price; $scope.totalAmount += item.total; } });`

Comment: hey  how to display the usename - here "user1 " display only one time   or two times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you. I use nested `angular#forEach` and after summing amounts that have same username , remove it from array.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.data = [{
  "id": 1,
  "amount": 24000000,
  "users": {
    "username": "user1"
  }
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "amount": 10000000,
  "users": {
    "username": "user1"
  }
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "amount": 20000000,
  "users": {
    "username": "user2"
  }
}];

$scope.totalAmount = 0; 
angular.forEach($scope.data,function(item,index){
  var temp = $scope.data[index];
  $scope.totalAmount =temp.amount;
  var tempIndex = index;
  angular.forEach($scope.data,function(item,index){
    if (index == tempIndex){ 
     return;
   }else{
     if (temp.users.username == item.users.username){ 
       $scope.totalAmount += item.amount; 
       $scope.data.splice(index, 1); //removing after summing
     }
   }
  });
  temp.amount = $scope.totalAmount;
  $scope.totalAmount = 0;
 });
 
});
```

```html
<script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <table>
   <tr data-ng-repeat="cart in data track by $index">
    <td>{{cart.users.username}}</td>
    <td>{{cart.amount}}</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, great help for my work. Sorry to bother you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to sum the items belonging to a particular user:

```js
let data = [{
  "id": 1,
  "amount": 24000000,
  "users": {
    "username": "user1"
  }
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "amount": 10000000,
  "users": {
    "username": "user1"
  }
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "amount": 20000000,
  "users": {
    "username": "user2"
  }
}];

function sumFor(username) {
  return data.reduce((sum, item) => {
    if (item.users.username === username) {
      sum += item.amount;
    }
    return sum;
  }, 0);
}

console.log(sumFor('user1'));
```

Now, you can define the function `sumFor` as a member of the `$scope` and call it from the template.

Comment: Thank you sir, great help for my work. Sorry to bother you :). But i chose  [Gurkan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5371590/gurkan-yesilyurt) answer.